# How to get large number in table based on BookID

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, linq

I have a table like this,

```
ID  BookID  Sunday  Monday  Tuesday Wednesday   Thursday    Friday

001 B200    50      40      60      80           90           10
002 B200    10      20      40      50           80           30
003 B200    70      80      10      20           30           50
004 B500    40      50      90      10           60           40
005 B500    10      5       40      70           40           10
006 B500    50      40      50      40           100          50
007 B500    60      25      15      20           10           60
```

I need to get the largest number of the rows based on `bookID`. According to this table,

Ex:

- When BookID  = B200 , the largest number should be 90
- When BookID  = B500 , the largest number should be 100

how to get this value using C# LINQ query based on `BookID`.

Comment: this only a tip, normalize your table's fields (ID, BOOKID, DAY, Value) for better future

Comment: @cyan I can't change the table, because data insertion of table happening through the bot. so I can't change it

Comment: No field named `Saturday`?

Comment: @BobJarvis good observation - shop closed on this day;)

Comment: I work for a major retailer in the US. I'm confident that if it were possible our stores would be open nine days a week.

Comment: @BobJarvis - maybe the bookshop observes Shabbat?

Comment: Thanks - couldn't remember the right word. :-)

Answer (score 0):

First get the *geatest* count per the day of the week - using the function `GREATEST`

```
select id, BOOKID, greatest(SUNDAY, MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY) max_week from tab

        ID BOOKID   MAX_WEEK
---------- ------ ----------
         1 B200           90 
         2 B200           80 
         3 B200           80 
         4 B500           90 
         5 B500           70 
         6 B500          100 
         7 B500           60
```

Than simple use the `max` aggregated function

```
with mx as (
select id, BOOKID, greatest(SUNDAY, MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY) max_week from tab)
select BOOKID, max(max_week) max_week 
from mx
group by BOOKID
;

BOOKID   MAX_WEEK
------ ----------
B200           90 
B500          100
```

You may define the last query as a *view* and query it comfortably using your ORM.

```
create or replace view max_per_week as          
with mx as (
select id, BOOKID, greatest(SUNDAY, MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY) max_week from tab)
select BOOKID "BookID" , max(max_week) "MaxWeek"
from mx
group by BOOKID
;


var largestNumber = context.max_per_week.Where(s => s.BookID == "B200")
                       .Select(s => new int[] { s.MaxWeek})
```

Comment: OP wants a LINQ solution.

Comment: @BobJarvis This is how would I solve it in LINQ using an Oracle view.

Comment: Nice save... :-)

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that the columns have to be `NOT NULL` (or else use `nvl`/`coalesce` expressions), as any null value will give a null `greatest()`. (In this case I'm guessing the store would record zero sales and never null, so may not be an issue.)

Answer (score 0):

**Solution using method syntax**

So you have a sequence of `Books`, where every `Book` has an `Id`, a `BookId` and a number for most days of the week (CopiesSoldCount?).

From this table you want to extract from every `Book` the `BookId` and the largest `CopiesSoldCount`. Possibly you only want the result from only the `Book` with a given `bookId`.

```
int bookId = ...
var result = Books
    .Where(book => book.BookId == bookId)
    .Select(book => new
    {
        BookId = bookId,
        MaxCopiesSole = new int[]
        {
             book.Monday, book.Tuesday, book.Wednesday, book.Thursday, book.Friday,
        }
        .Max(),
    });
```

In words: from the sequence of `Books`, keep only the `Books` that have a `BookId` equal to `bookId`. From every remaining `Book` make one new object with a property `BookId` and the maximum value of the integer array `book.Monday`, `book.Tuesday`, ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code
link for [Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GtW50R)
//Create Class

```
 public class Book
 {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string BookID { get; set; }
        public int Sunday { get; set; }
        public int Monday { get; set; }
        public int Tuesday { get; set; }
        public int Wednesday { get; set; }
        public int Thursday { get; set; }
        public int Friday { get; set; }
  }

         var result = (from item in itemList
                      group item by item.BookID into groupData
                      select new
                      {
                          BookID = groupData.Key,
                          MaxNo = (from sub in groupData
                                   select new int[]
                                   {
                                       sub.Sunday,
                                       sub.Monday,
                                       sub.Tuesday,
                                       sub.Wednesday,
                                       sub.Thursday,
                                       sub.Friday
                                   }).ToList()
                      }).ToList();

       //Get Max Element
       var finalResult= (from item in result
                        select new
                        {
                            item.BookID,
                            No = (from i in item.MaxNo
                                  from ii in i
                                  orderby ii descending
                                  select ii).FirstOrDefault()


                        });
```